# Spring Data Rest and Rest Controller together

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I'm using Spring Data Rest and have `@RepositoryRestResource` defined with the path is `"pathXYZ"`. Now I have a class with `@RestController` and defined a `@GetMapping` with `"pathXYZ/custom"`.

It seems `"pathXYZ/custom"` is not able to serve.

If I changed `"pathXYZ/custom"` to `"pathABC/custom"`, it is working as normal.

Is that the way to have `@RestController` and `@RespositoryRestResource` working on the same 'base' context path?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to annotate your MVC Controller with @RepositoryRestController instead of @RestController

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers